# Как пропарсить JSON в PHP POST

Tags: php, json, mvc

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как осуществить парсинг...

Здесь формируется массив объектов **stageArr**

```
$scope.addContract = function() {

    var stageCount = angular.element("#stage").val();
    var stageArr = [];
    for (let i = 1; i<=stageCount;i++){

        var stageNameInfo = "#stageName"+i;
        var dateBegin1Info = "#dateBegin"+i;
        var dateEndInfo = "#dateEnd"+i;
        $scope.stageName = angular.element(stageNameInfo).val();
        $scope.dateBegin = angular.element(dateBegin1Info).val();
        $scope.dateEnd = angular.element(dateEndInfo).val();


        stageArr[i] = [{
            name: $scope.stageName,
            dateBegin: $scope.dateBegin,
            dateEnd: $scope.dateEnd
        }
        ]

    }
    $scope.stageArr = stageArr;
    
    $scope.nameDp = angular.element("#nameDp").val();
    $scope.contractNumber = angular.element("#contractNumber").val();
    $scope.contractTitle = angular.element("#contractTitle").val();
    $scope.contractDate = angular.element("#contractDate").val();

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/cabinet/contracts/addContract",
        data: $.param({
            nameDp: $scope.nameDp,
            contractNumber: $scope.contractNumber,
            contractTitle: $scope.contractTitle,
            contractDate: $scope.contractDate,
            stage: $scope.stageArr
        }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function(result){
    
       
    }) 

}
```

**Контроллер** Здесь я вроде не правильно даже получаю JSON через POST ($stage) ,_,

```
    public function addContract() {
if(!$_SESSION['user']) {
    header("Location: /");
    return;
}

    $nameDp = $_SESSION['user'];
    $contractNumber = trim($_POST['contractNumber']);
    $contractTitle = trim($_POST['contractTitle']);
    $contractDate = trim($_POST['contractDate']);
    $stage = $_POST['stage'];
    $array1 = json_decode($stage);
  
    if($this->model->addContract($nameDp, $contractNumber,$contractTitle, $contractDate,$array1)) {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => true));
     
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => false));
    
}
```

}

**Модель** Здесь нужно обратиться к элементам массива array1

```
 public function addContract($nameDp, $contractNumber,$contractTitle, $contractDate, $array1) {




$sql = "INSERT INTO contract(department, numberContract, nameContract, dateConclusion)
VALUES(:department, :numberContract, :nameContract, :dateConclusion)
";
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindValue(":department", $nameDp, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue(":numberContract", $contractNumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue(":nameContract", $contractTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue(":dateConclusion", $contractDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();

  $sql1= "SELECT contract.idContract FROM contract WHERE contract.numberContract = :num";

  $stmt1 = $this->db->prepare($sql1);
  $stmt1->bindValue(":num", $contractNumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt1->execute();
  $idCont=$stmt1->fetchColumn();

 

  foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
  {
     $stageName = $value['name'];
     $stageDateBegin =  $value['dateBegin'];
     $stageDateEnd = $value['dateEnd'];

     $sql2 = "INSERT INTO stage(contracrt, dtSt_begin, dtSt_begin, number_stage) VALUES(:id, :dtSt_begin, :dtSt_end, :number_stage)";
    $stmt2 = $this->db->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt2->bindValue(":id", $idCont['idContract'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt2->bindValue(":dtSt_begin", $stageDateBegin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt2->bindValue(":dtSt_end", $stageDateEnd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt2->bindValue(":number_stage", $stageName, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt2->execute();
```

}

}

Comment: Вы можете предоставить логи $_POST, $stage и  $array1 с сервера? Думаю там сразу будет видна ваша проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужен ассоциативный массив, то укажите при декодировании вторым аргументом true:

```
  $array1 = json_decode($stage, true);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Принимаемые данные с фронта, должны быть в кодировке UTF-8.

Также обратите внимание, как у вас происходит добавление элементов в массив. Вы добавляете объект обернутый в массив. Вам достаточно объекта.

```
stageArr.push({
    name: $scope.stageName,
    dateBegin: $scope.dateBegin,
    dateEnd: $scope.dateEnd
})
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Теперь получается, чтобы обратиться к элементам массива нужно делать так?


      foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)

Comment: Да, чтобы перебрать весь массив, нужно так, а чтобы получить значения свойств name, dateBegin, dateEnd, нужно обращаться к $value['name'] и т.п.

Comment: обновил код модели, он выше. В таблицу contract все заносится, а в stage ничего..........

Comment: Воспользуйтесь командами var_dump($array11) или print_r($array1), посмотрите на содержимое данных. Если у вас произойдет обращение к несуществующему свойству массива, то будет исключение, т.к. конца сценария не должно быть достигнуто.